# Resolve or refactor using statements in MonoDevelop 3.0

Tags: monodevelop

One feature I miss tremendously now I switched from Visual Studio to MonoDevelop (for MonoTouch), is automatic using statement completion when a type cannot be recognised.

As I read from SO question [“Organize imports” in MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2089905/70182), this feature used to be implemented in version 2.2. However, as I also read from SO question [Override/Implement Members in MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12039846/70182), this feature regressed as of 3.0.

For now, I have to fall back to searching the full namespace of a type, and add the using statement manually.

Are there workarounds or plans to rebuild the feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out MonoDevelop does support the *Resolve* function, but it does not show it with a dropdown menu like in Visual Studio. You need to *right-click the type*, and then in the context menu the Resolve option will appear like below:

[image: Context menu on a type showing the Resolve menu option]

Comment: It would be great if there was a keyboard shortcut for this.

Answer (score 3):

I find using Ctrl+Alt+Space very helpful it lets you type the typename of the class you are looking for (Amongs the references assemblies) and will then automatically add the using statement if it is needed.